# How do I declare and define my variable to be nullable?

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have a custom class;

```
interface IMyType {
  foo: string
  bar?: IChild
}
```

Now I want to optionally instantiate that type:

```
var myType: IMyType = null
if (something) { myType = somethingNotNull }
```

This results in;

> TS2322: Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'IMyType'.

So now I can do this:

```
var myType: IMyType | null = null
```

And that seems to work, but now I've got my optionals declared using "?" in the class declaration, and using "| null" elsewhere, which seems really ugly/messy/incorrect. What's the correct way to achieve consistent optional behaviour in typescript?

Comment: Writing `var myType: IMyType | null` is the correct way to make it nullable. When it can be `null` in another place as well, it has to be declared the same way there. You can make null check though to get rid of the nullable type elsewhere

Comment: You can use a more readable version of it like this `type Nullable<T> = T | null;` and define your variable like this `var myType: Nullable<IMyType> = null`

Comment: I think there is a tslint option to allow this. My Angular project allows this at least, but I don't know what configuration is responsible for allowing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to my comment, here is a minimal working example.

When a field is nullable, it's type will be `MyType | null`. If you want to get rid of the `null` part, you can either check for `null` or cast it to the non-nullable type. Casting however is risky because the casted variable might still be `null`.

Or put the null-check inline with `??` and specify the value in case of null.

```js
interface IMyType {
  foo: string, 
  bar?: string,
}

var somethingNotNull: IMyType = {foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar'};

var nullableMyType: IMyType | null = null;

const shouldNotBeNull = false;
if (shouldNotBeNull) {
  nullableMyType = somethingNotNull;
}

var casted: IMyType = nullableMyType as IMyType; // dangerous because casted pretends to be not nullable, but still might be null if myType is null

// var notNull: IMyType = myType; // does not compile: Type 'IMyType | null' is not assignable to type 'IMyType'

if (nullableMyType !== null) {
  var notNull: IMyType = nullableMyType; // does compile
}

var notNull: IMyType = nullableMyType ?? {foo: '', bar: ''}; // Specify value for the null case
```